# What makes the benefit of defaulted counterparty risk asymmetric in an interest swap?

Tags: interest-rate-swap, counterparty-risk, default-risk

On page 369 of *Quantitative Risk Management (2015)* by McNeil, Frey, and Embrechts, there is an interesting example that I do not quite understand. Suppose A makes a floating interest rate payment to B, and B pays a fixed interest to A, but now A defaults. The book says:

> If interest rates have risen
> relative to their value at inception of the contract, the fixed interest payments have
> *decreased* in value so that the value of the swap contract has increased for B.

> On the other hand, if interest rates have fallen relative to their value at
> t = 0, the fixed payments have increased in value so that the swap has a negative
> value for B. At settlement, **B will still have to pay the value of the contract into the
> bankruptcy pool**, so that there is *no upside* for B in A’s default.

I am not quite familiar with the rules here, which seems to be the key. Does the words in bold mean, depending on which rate is higher, B pays differently? Alternatively, should the debt of a higher interest rate be paid first, just like the senior CDO trench?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If Mr. A owes you money and he cannot pay you, you lose. If you owe money to A and A cannot pay B, C, ..., Z so he goes bankrupt, you still have to pay what you owe to A.  So when you owe Mr. A money there is no advantage for you if he goes bankrupt. This the asymmetry.

Comment: I herad (but never found a reference, so this may all be an urban legend / hypothetical / exaggeration) that in the early days of swaps (1970s), before netting agreements, some bankruptcy judge severed and cherry-picked the legs of IR swap:  B still pays entire fixed to A, but A got some holiday on paying floating to B.

Comment: @noob2 If the non-default party has to pay the same rate regardless of the counter party, then it seems meaningless to assume defaults here. Please correct me if I were wrong.

Comment: It is not "meaningless" to analyze this case, but the analysis shows that in this case the gain or loss from default is zero.